# How to remove spacing in a string?

Tags: python, space, python-3.3

I am using Python 3.3.

For example, if I opened a file and read the first line using `file.readline()`, I will get a string of the first line.

Let's say the first line is: `line = file.readline()`.

`line` will now be: `'Dumbledore, Albus\n'`.

If I used:

```
a = line.strip().split(',')
```

I will get: `['Dumbledore', ' Albus']`

This is where I'm encountering the problem. I do not want the extra space before the first name `'Albus'`.

What (simple) approach can I use to remove this?

The purpose of this entire task is to swap the first and last names (for example, from `'Dumbledore, Albus'` to `'Albus, Dumbledore'`.

Comment: There are various ways to handle this depending on your programming language. It would be useful to mention the programming language in the question or in the tags.

Comment: I'm a new-user to Python, so I'm not too into depth with the more complex methods. Do you mind elaborating? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `str.strip()`:

```
s = 'Dumbledore, Albus'
l = [x.strip() for x in s.split(',')]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you used the `strip()` function on your `readline()` output, you used the correct tool that you want to use, albeit at a wrong place.

```
>>> ' a '.strip()
'a'
```

Specifically, in your context, you may want to do something like this

```
>>> a = ['Dumbledore', ' Albus']
>>> a = [x.strip() for x in a]
>>> a
['Dumbledore', 'Albus']
```

What you are doing is a very simple [list comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) and assigning the final result to the original array.

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted, as far as I can tell this is exactly what I suggested... Upvoting!

Answer (score 0):

You can try in Python:

```
input = ['Dumbledore', ' Albus']
output = [re.sub(' *', '', x) for x in input]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to use a strip or lstrip

```
a = ['Dumbledore', ' Albus']
a = [item.strip() for item in a]
```

Given your last edit

```
names = []
for line in open(myfile).readlines(): #read and act on each line sequentially
    line_list = line.split(',')     # split each line on the comma
    line_list = [item.strip() for line in line_list] # get rid of spaces and newlines
    line_list.reverse()  # reverse the list
    new_name_order = ','.join(line_list)   # join the items with a comma
    names.append(new_name_order)   # add the name to the list of names
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to just split on `', '` instead of `','`. So you do:

```
a = line.strip().split(', ')
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness you could also use a regular expression:

```
import re

line = 'Dumbledore, Albus\n'
reformatted = re.sub('(.*?), (.*)', r'\2, \1', line)
# Albus, Dumbledore
```

Which could be adapted to be:

```
rx = re.compile('(.*?), (.*?)\n')
with open('yourfile') as fin:
    lines = [rx.sub('\2, \1', line) for line in fin]
```

Answer (score 0):

As a one-liner:

```
', '.join([x.strip() for x in line.split(',')][::-1])
```

*Note:* `[::-1]` reverses a list, i.e:

```
[1, 2, 3][::-1]
=> [3, 2, 1]
```

A bit clearer for your situation:

```
lastname, firstname = [x.strip() for x in line.split(',')]
name = firstname + ', ' + lastname
```